# My string is initialized, but still shows up as null (flutter - dart)

Tags: string, flutter, dart, text

I hope you are doing well!

I am working on a simple string tutorial with flutter and I ran into this issue regarding strings and the Text widget. I'm trying to create a string variable in my _MyHomePageState class, but my displayTxt is appearing null, even though I set a value to it. I used interpolation to see what value it contained and, sure enough, it was null. I'm semi-new to dart and flutter, so any and all help is appreciated.

Have a great day!

- List item

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  **String displayTxt = "Hello";**

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Some text here",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 45,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    letterSpacing: 2,
                    shadows: [
                      Shadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        offset: Offset(-5,-5),
                      ),
                    ],
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => {},
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.airplanemode_active,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Text('press me'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  highlightColor: Colors.white10,
                  elevation: 10,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  **child: Text("${displayTxt}"),**
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Pasting this code into DartPad shows no errors and the string appears as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem, turns out when you don't have the string in use in a function, it appears null. That's my simple explanation, but if someone with more experience can elaborate, that would be helpful.

I added this and then no more errors

```
 onPressed: () => setState(() {
                this.displayTxt = 'Some text to display';
              }),
```

Comment: Again, your original code worked as expected with no null strings. If there is an error in your program, it's not in the code you posted. As it stands, I can't imagine what issue you had with that code that is fixed with this solution.